# Node.js Just starting

Tags: node.js, terminal

i'm following the lynda.com tutorials, love this site, i got my hello world with console.log()

my next task is to try this script

```
var os = required('os');

var message = 'This script is running on Node.js ' + process.version + ' on a ' 
+ os.type() + '-based operating system.';

console.log(message);
```

my error in the terminal

```
ReferenceError: required is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ArtSir/nodeJS/script.js:1:72)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

I double checked my spelling and check my semicolons (that doesn't really matter in node.js like javascript right) but yea any help? i just started. I don't understand why required is not defined, i installed node. was i suppose to install 'os'?

Comment: read the error: required is not defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `require`, withoud d:

```
var os = require('os');
```